# Facebook PHP SDK login work in index page only

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

(All URLs excluded "http://" as I've got insufficent reputation... sorry)

I've successfully do log in with facebook account in my website.

But it only work in index page only. (The URL matched with the facebook app website setting)

example:

The website url setting in the facebook app is : www.abc.com

The login work in the page: www.abc.com

BUT not work in www.abc.com/XXX

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXX',
  'secret' => 'YYYY'
));
$facebook_user = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump($facebook_user);
//return user information in http://www.abc.com
//BUT return 0 in http://www.abc.com/XXXX
```

Any advise? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit code that can solve the problem;

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXX', 
  'secret' => 'YYYY', 
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

best regards.